# Catch 'no results found' in Parse PFQuery

Tags: objective-c, performance, parse-platform, error-handling

When using the PFQuery, if no results are found it just outputs it to the console but does not let me handle the error in the code. I have not found this documented on their site so I hope to seek help here. I am using:

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
```

to try to find the objects. I have tried seeing if **objects was nil**, **error was nil**, and if **objects.count was equal to zero** but **none of the above worked**.

Does anyone know how to handle the case of the result not being in the query using a PFQuery? Thank you.

EDIT 10/10/2015: My Code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
        [query getObjectWithId:s];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && [objects count] > 0) {
                // The find succeeded.

                }
            }else if ([objects count] == 0) {
                // Should run when there is nothing found
            }

            else {
                // Log details of the failure
            }
        }];
```

When I run the query and get no results, nothing in the block runs.

Comment: objects.count == 0 should work.  what did you see?  we wouldn't expect the db or the backend to treat empty results as an error.

Comment: It seems to ignore all that is in my block statement as I have some NSLogs in there that were just supposed to print no matter the condition but they did not. Objects.count == 0 did not work nor did !objects.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Code Added in edit 10/10/2015

Comment: The only thing strange about it is `getObjectWithId`.  Please remove that line.  If it still doesn't work, you can improve your question further by supplying *proof* that its not working as expected.  Run the code with NSLogs in the completion block, post *that* code.  Post that log output (stating that objects count was found to be zero), post an image from the parse data browser showing how there are rows there.